# Have I found a bug in the Sonos Self-test Suite?

Tags: testing, sonos

### Summary

The Sonos self-test suite seems to incorrectly fail for an item with `itemType=other` if it also has a custom browse icon.

I believe that the item type `other` should be included in this list from `utility.py`:

```
  17     BROWSEABLE_CONTAINER_TYPES = ('artist', 'album', 'genre', 'playlist', 'favorites', 'albumList', 'trackList', 'artistTrackList', 'container', 'favorite', 'collection', 'program', 'show')
```

### Details

When running the sonos self-test suite, I got the following error as part of the output:

```
...
INFO Start Test Case: 844 Albumart test_custom_browse_icon_configuration
STOP Discovered custom browse icon URI should be something other than None. (is None)
STOP 844 Albumart test_custom_browse_icon_configuration
...
```

By debugging `albumart.py` (`test_custom_browse_icon_configuration` method), I traced the issue to the following extract of the `get_sample_custom_browse_icon_url` method:

```
  # TODO: Need to drill down one level deeper if the target image url cannot be found on the root level containers
  for mediaColl in response.Items:
      if mediaColl.itemType in container_types:
          if substitution_str in mediaColl.albumArtURI:
              return mediaColl.albumArtURI
          elif hasattr(mediaColl.albumArtURI,'value') and substitution_str in mediaColl.albumArtURI.value:
              return  mediaColl.albumArtURI.value
```

This code was supposed to find containers with custom album art. However, it turns out that `container_types` was defined by an earlier line:

```
  container_types = [t for t in Validation.BROWSEABLE_CONTAINER_TYPES if t.lower() != 'album']
```

and `Validation.BROWSEABLE_CONTAINER_TYPES` was defined in `utility.py` as follows:

```
  # sonos-selftest/smapi/content_workflow/utility.py
  15 class Validation(WorkflowTestFixture, SMAPIClient, SMAPIService):
  16
  17     BROWSEABLE_CONTAINER_TYPES = ('artist', 'album', 'genre', 'playlist', 'favorites', 'albumList', 'trackList', 'artistTrackList', 'container', 'favorite', 'collection', 'program', 'show')
```

Note that the type `'other'` is missing from this list! I'm pretty sure it is supposed to be inluded in the list, `browse.py` mentions it:

```
234         **Reference:** BROWSEABLE_CONTAINER_TYPES = 'artist', 'album', 'genre', 'playlist', 'favorites', 'albumList', 'trackList', 'artistTrackList', 'container', 'favorite', 'collection', 'other', '    program'
```

### Workaround

I was able to work around this issue by changing `itemType=other` to `itemType=container` (which are pretty much equivalent).

However, it would be nice if this was fixed in future versions of the Sonos self-test suite.